# gold badge for questions, when exactly is it awarded?

Tags: discussion

I have asked [a question](https://superuser.com/questions/1502796/how-do-i-activate-windowsxp-now-that-support-has-ended) that has 99 up votes. Just out of curiosity, when exactly is the question gold badge awarded? For the absolute up votes or the relative up votes subtracting the down votes? Note, it has two downvotes (unfortunately as usually without any explanations so the question could be improved, but that's a different issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Just out of curiosity, when exactly is the question gold badge awarded?

There are a number of badges that can be earned on a question. They are listed in
[Question Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#67399)

I assume you are referring to the following badge:

> **Great Question**
>
> - gold; awarded once per question
> - Earn a score of 100 on one question

Question score is defined as the combined total of up and down votes.

As [Journeyman Geek](https://meta.superuser.com/users/10165/journeyman-geek) points out in a comment, the badges are awarded by batch jobs so there may be a delay of a few hours to a day before the badges are awarded after the trigger point is reached.

Comment: yes, you are right, I forgot to link the question to make it clear.

Comment: There's  also a batch job for these things, so even if you hit the trigger there may be a  few hours to one day delay IIRC

Comment: thanks for the addition... still 2 votes missing... I'll be patient ;'D